# JQuery- How to retrieve class name from a Variable having html tag

Tags: jquery, variables, var

I am having variable .i.e. var `gtval` it return a image tag and now i want the fetch the class name of that img tag;

```
var gtval = aData[4];
alert(gtval);
```

alert display-

```
    <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_Image1" class="del_10 pointer" 
src="images/delete_item.png" style="border-width:0px;">
```

I want to fetch `del_10` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be just:

```
alert($(gtval).attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
```

To be sure older browsers will support it:

```
alert($($.trim(gtval)).attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much it works , actually i was trying `$(gtval).attr('class')` and its not worked

Answer (score 1):

```
var classList = gtval.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

Return list of used classes.

Comment: thnks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the value "del_10", Does the value have to be a className for starters?

```
<img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_Image1" rel="del_10" class="pointer" src="images/delete_item.png" style="border-width:0px;">

alert( $('#'+aData[4]).attr('rel') );
```

Otherwise the other answers given above should work. Though I imagine you need to inclode the hash as so:

```
alert( $('#'+aData[4]).attr('class').split(/\s+/)[0]; );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var className = $(gtval).map(function () {
    return this.className;
})[0].split(' ').join(',');

console.log(className); // result: del_10,pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could get the raw DOM and get the `classList`

```
 $(gtval)[0].classList
```